# Replace to string Regex Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Please help with Replace function. Now have next:

```
Text1,

Text2,

Text3,
```

Need get:

```
Text1, Text2, Text3,
```

What me need add to find and replace that get result?

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R+`
- Replace with:   <-- a space
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R+         # 1 or more any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Text1, Text2, Text3,
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]